# What is the reason for "locks are an expensive operation" to be uttered so often?

Tags: multithreading, performance, synchronization

I have read a lot of material on threading, and all the synchronization mechanisms involved.  I also understand the dangers of not doing it properly.

I just watched [this](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/P09-17) PDC 2009 video about Parallelism and Concurrency, and here is yet again this mention that "locks are an expensive operation".  I've now come across a phrase like this in various texts, books, and I've heard experts in the field say it too.

I was wondering, what exactly is so expensive about obtaining a lock (mutex or semaphore)?  Is it the fact that it causes a `LOCK#` instruction to be emitted at Assembler level?

Is it the fact that obtaining a lock requires a kernel call into the OS?

Why are locks considered to be an expensive operation? "Expensive" is a fairly relative term, so if we compared to creating a new thread (which requires setting up a thread stack, etc), how expensive is obtaining a lock really?

What goes on underneath the covers?

My guess is, that it cannot possibly that expensive, because I'm sure for Windows (for example) to run, hundreds of locks/synch mechanisms have to be used all the time.

Can anyone elaborate?

NOTE: I'm merely curious, I know how threading works, and I'm not looking to do some silly optimization either.

Comment: It is the memory barrier that's expensive.  50 nanoseconds on average on a x86 core.  This is pretty good: http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it the fact that it causes a LOCK# instruction to be emitted at Assembler level?

No, since it doesn't always do that.

> Is it the fact that obtaining a lock requires a kernel call into the OS?

No, since it typically doesn't do that.

In fact, locks are very, very inexpensive. It's *contention* that's expensive. If you have to choose between a lock and contention, most of the time the lock is a better option.

Locks, when used properly, are a contention *avoidance* mechanism. They automatically find threads that contend and de-schedule them such that one winds up primarily with threads that do not contend running concurrently.

For example: Say you have four threads that are ready to run, *A*, *B*, *C*, and *D*. Say *A* and *B* contend with each other (say they manipulate the same collection). And say *C* and *D* contend with each other, but *A* doesn't contend with *C*. If *A* and *B* are running at the same time (contending), the locks will cause one of them to not be ready to run, the scheduler will then schedule *C* (or *D*), and the two threads will run without further contention. (At least until the next context switch.)

Usually, when people say "locks are expensive", they mean that contention is expensive. Unfortunately, by phrasing it the way they do, they often encourage people to minimize locks but increase contention in the process. That is a losing proposition in the vast majority of cases. (There are a few exceptions.)

Comment: There's lock contention (which is not an issue for lock-free code) and cache contention (which still affects lock-free code).  Which is a bigger performance hit depends very much on the particular application.  Correctness is a much bigger deal.  Furthermore, it isn't usually locking vs lock-free code, but the granularity of the locks under discussion.  You never "choose between a lock and contention".

Comment: The articles claiming that "locks are expensive" are probably promoting a different design completely, such as message passing, which is both easier to get correct, and suffers from very little contention of either kind when properly applied.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're probably right. In which case, I'd answer the question like this: "Message passing is implemented, under the hood, with locks. So this isn't a criticism of locks themselves but a criticism of designing at the level where you're the one using the locks. This is frequently quite correct because locks are very easy to misuse, whereas message passing (for example) is harder to misuse."

Comment: Message passing might well have locks, or could be lock-less (it's fairly easy to write a lock-less single-consumer queue, harder to get good performance, but in message passing there's one hotspot on which all attention can be focused).  But the important thing, for both correctness and performance, is that in message passing systems, shared data is minimized.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, it can be implemented with or without locks. And that has basically no effect on performance. (Which kind of proves that locks aren't the issue.) As I said, contention is the issue. When message passing helps performance, it's usually because it minimizes contention.

Comment: Yes, it minimizes contention.  By forcing the design to reduce sharing.  Not by stopping threads in the hope that the system has an unrelated process ready to run.  If the goal is to make progress on as many independent problems at once, write each single-threaded and forget about locks.  That way the other N-1 cores are always available for scheduling something else.  But usually the goal is to complete this task as fast as possible, and lock-induced sleeps don't help with that.

Comment: @BenVoigt Usually the goal is for the system as a whole to make forward progress as quickly as possible. If that's not the goal, then almost everything (starting with the scheduler) is designed wrong. (And what a big mistake we made going to pre-emptive multitasking!)

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said that usually the goal is maximal progress on a single problem.  But that's the case we care about when talking about locks, because the multi-user/multi-tasking case is trivially handled by staying single-threaded within each request.

Answer (score 10):

#### Parallelism

**When mutable shared data requires a lock, you could lose the benefits of parallelism.**

Let's first make the simplification that context switches are free and locks are cheap (neither of which is exactly true - we will address these points at the end).

- Think about the case of threads that share no data: threads can run
  **independently** without worrying about the state of other threads.  Having two threads will make your algorithm run twice as fast.
- Next, introduce some piece of shared data which changes over time.
  By definition, no two threads can be modifying/reading this data at
  the same time.  That means if two threads happen to want access to
  this data, you no longer have concurrent operation: they must work in
  a serialized (synchronized) manner.  The more frequently this
  contention happens, the more your application will behave like a
  single-threaded application than a dual-threaded app.

*So when it is said that "locks are an expensive operation", I take it to mean that it is due to the potential loss of parallelism rather than the lock itself being expensive.*

#### Costs

In addition to the loss of parallelism, if you accumulate the small, but non-zero costs of locks and potential synchronization and context switches, having locks can very likely slow down your algorithm.

Also note that the more threads you have trying to access that lock at the same time, the more your algorithm will appear to run serially rather than in parallel.  The OS will also have to spend more cycles juggling all the contexts through that small straw created by the lock.

#### Mitigation

On the other hand, the drawbacks of having locks can be mitigated by not calling them often, not thrashing (locking/unlocking once rather than lock/unlock many times within a tight block), or by the use of pipelines or consumer/producer patterns (signaling with condition variables).

One trick for lockless operations includes doing all your shared data initialization before spawning any threads and only reading from that data after spawning.

#### Terminology

One last comment: locks are needed to avoid **race conditions** on a shared resource.  **Contentions** are just a consequence of having locks - it just means one thread can be blocked/waiting on a lock that another thread has locked.  How often contentions happen actually depends on many factors: number of threads vs cores, how much time is spent in the lock, luck of the execution (dependent on the scheduling algorithm), the state of your OS during the run, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Locks are expensive because they block other threads from obtaining the lock. The delays can be deadly, making a multi-processor system slower than a single-threaded design without locks.

Comment: This is a misconception. You don't want the other threads to obtain the lock because then they'd fight over the shared data (causing horrible cache ping-ponging and awful performance). That locks deschedule contending threads so that they *don't* run concurrently (and thus don't fight over shared data) is their big benefit. (When they are used properly, of course.) Locks are cheap, contention is expensive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Locks are shared objects, that cause contention.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I suppose this is true in theory, but I've never in my life seen such a thing except in code where locks were horribly misused by beginners who thought they needed to lock *code* rather than data. I've only ever seen locks used where the *data* contends already, with or without the lock. And the lock *prevents* contending access to the data -- that's its purpose.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm under the impression that building-block design tends to "grab a thread-safe collection object" where all operations take a lock.  And then that lock becomes a point of contention, even when all threads would otherwise be accessing different elements of the array and not contending.  Or people "solve" their sharing/contention problem by adding locks, instead of redesigning to minimize sharing.  `malloc` is a classic suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Locks are often spinlocks, which cause a thread to "spin" doing no useful work when the lock is taken.

Doing nothing is expensive, since, as everyone knows: "time is money".

Comment: Surely unless the person who implemented your locking primitives was brain damaged or something, the locks wouldn't spin unless this provided a benefit. You're essentially arguing that locks are bad because they're badly implemented. That can't be (and isn't) right.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No, they're not expensive.

The longer answer is: Yes, they're expensive because unless your locks are pointless and do nothing, the presence of locks will slow down your code.

The actual answer requires a clarification:

Technical vs. Implementation vs. Design:

**Technical:** [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) answer clarifies that [technically the locks do not slow down code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012164/59808) That is, if you run single threaded code with lock statements in it the locks will not slow you down.*

**Implementation:** [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012154/59808) that locks are slow because the blocks cause delays which lead to a slower app.

**Design:** The real answer is that a design which includes locks tends to be slower than designs which don't. Locks are *designed* to slow down your code.

So, if you can reasonably manage to write code where the locks are never hit or not even needed, you absolutely should. That is why people say "locks are expensive." It is not that the `lock(obj)` statement is expensive, it is that the act of blocking other threads is expensive, and should only be undertaken in situations where you've evaluated that it is worth the expense.

*<sup>Of course, if you get lock contention in a single threaded app, it will never finish.</sup>

Comment: "Locks are designed to slow down your code." No, not at all. This is the misconception I'm talking about. Locks are designed to speed up your code by permitting threads that *don't* contend to run concurrently at full speed, rather than allowing threads that do contend to run concurrently at a snail's pace. (If threads A and B contend but C doesn't, locks will tend to make A run with C rather than B, speeding up the system overall by avoiding the cache ping-ponging that would occur if A and B ran at the same time.)

Comment: @David false. "permitting threads that don't contend to run concurrently". This is possible without locks. The purpose of locking code is to ensure that only ONE thread is going through a block at a time. This means that the other thread must WAIT. Without a lock, the other thread doesn't wait. This is FASTER, but usually WRONG.

Comment: Without locks, threads that contend will happily run at the same time, ping-ponging data back and forth between caches and killing system performance. By only allowing one thread in the block that contains the accesses to shared data to run at a time, threads that contend don't run concurrently. The other **thread** must WAIT, but so what? Making a thread that would run slowly with heavy cache contention wait so you can run a thread that will run at full speed without cache contention makes the *system* faster. Locks are designed to speed up your code by avoiding contention.

Comment: @David in the case of your caching example, or in any long running operation that needs to be done only once, you are correct, locks will make it run faster, but this is because it is a READ-ONLY operation (meaning that the second operation doesn't *rely* on the first operation).

Comment: @David, I disagree, but you pointed out something that we've both done wrong. Locks are not *designed* to affect performance in any way. Locks are *designed* to ensure that only one thread goes through a code block at one time. Applications use this in whatever way they can. In your scenarios, locks will improve performance. In my scenarios locks will degrade performance and improve accuracy. They are both valid uses of locks.

Comment: If operation Y relies on the results of operation X in order to execute correctly, then locks (or some similar mechanism to force the ordering) are *required* for correct operation. Whether they make the code faster or slower doesn't matter -- we only care about comparing execution times among *correct* execution paths. (You are quite correct that locks can also be used to make code execute correctly, but in this case, their performance implications are irrelevant. We **must** make our code execute correctly even if that makes it perform terribly.)

Comment: @David: The performance implications of locks are irrelevant only if there's no other design which correctly solves the problem.  Just because *this* design cannot operate correctly without locks, does not mean that the costs of locking are a mandatory expense.